# Post in Google+ community via android

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to post what a user type in an EditText, let's call it bugDescription_text, inside a Google+ community.

I know how to show the community in Google+ app, and I know how to share something on Google+, but looks like there is no way to post something just in the community.

Does any of you know how to achieve this?

The code to share something on Google+ is:

```
TextView bugDescription_text = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.buDescription_text));
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
                                  .setType("text/plain")
                                  .setText(bugDescription_text.getText().toString())
                                  .set(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/communities/115754662037454223862"))
                                  .getIntent();

startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Posting is available only in Google+ Domains API https://developers.google.com/+/domains/getting-started. But I think you could deploy something like http://www.nextscripts.com/google-plus-automated-posting/ to your server.

Comment: @DmitryL. I have no web server, should I use Google+ Domains API thus? Do you know of any example on the web?